# Как узнать список всех файлов директории в ubuntu?

Tags: linux

Как узнать список всех файлов директории в ubuntu?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В терминале выполнить команду

```
ls -la
```

или команду

```
ll
```

Answer (score 2):

Выводит список файлов с их путями в корневой директории, а так же подпапках

```
find ./ -type f
```

P.S Добавил ответ, так как в гугле искал именно это)

Comment: Плюсую ответ и добавлю от себя в комментарии, что вывод будет очень большим и лучше его для удобности сразу записать в отдельный файл, после вышеприведенного ещё добавить `>> /home/your_user/your_file.txt` , но тут вопрос касался скорее всего просто одной взятой директории, а не корневой, по крайней мере вопрос так не стоял. Но всё-равно ответ может пригодится тем кто будет искать.